# Por que mi proyecto de django, en cpanel, tarda demasiado en subir y imagenes

Tags: python, django, cpanel

Configure las rutas en settings.py, para redirigirlas a public_html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando realice el despliegue pude registrar en la base de datos, subir imagenes correctamente, cambiar la información y todo, pero luego de un dia al intentar registrar e intentar subir imagenes simplemente se queda cargando, y luego sale un error 500, estoy intentando solucionar, pero realmente no entiendo que es lo que pasa.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb24U.png)

Necesito ayuda he utilizado algun tiempo Django, pero es la primera ves que uso Cpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: valida los permisos de las carpetas en tu cpanel hay una opcion para los permisos

Comment: Se encuentra todo con los permisos 7 7 7, al principio si me tope con ese error pero lo pude solucionar, pero ahora no se cual es el problema